# WordPress: Editing custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've to do some edits to wordPress theme home page . This is the scenario.

There are 4 posts being showed in home page under news  tab  now when i check this is  using front-page template and in  front-page template I've something like this

```
<?php
    wp_reset_query();
    $loop = new WP_Query(  array( 'post_type' => 'news', 'posts_per_page' => 4 , 'orderby ' => 'date' , 'order' => 'DESC' )  );
           // $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
      while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
```

Now when i try to find out  post type for news i dont find it .so if there is no custom post type for this  what  could be other option for  this? please someone help me with  it how can i figure this out .

Comment: Have you created custom post type first?

Comment: @KaushaMehta i'm working with theme customization done by someone else . now there is no  post type/ tab in my dashboard

Comment: Then first you have to create the custom post type with the name "News", then you can use that custom post type to your homepage.

Comment: but there is a section being pulled from somewhere called news. there is no custom type for that , no page and query is as per above statement . when i click to read more that takes me to 404

Comment: When you click read more then where you redirect?

Comment: You need to check in your `wp_posts` table what is the `post_type` of these posts

Comment: @KaushaMehta that takes me to 404

Comment: Ok, but i'm asking for the URL, what is the url for the read more page?

Comment: site.com/we-are-hiring-in-uae/

Comment: my site is online and i'm in phpmyadmin what should be table name i've db called site_db there is no  table called wp_posts

Comment: Maybe a silly question here but did u check out functions.php? for the custom post type...

Comment: there's definitely already a post type `news`; do a research for `register_post_type` on your theme and plugins files